# JS Date seconds gives different date in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I'm developing an small eCommerce where the customer main server is sending `Date` as seconds as `GET` parameter. Based on that I have to check if the `Date` minutes send from them is no more than `20` minutes in the current `DateTime`.

The problem so far is that the `C# DateTime` is always **3 hours** before the `Date` send from their server.

If I do `new Date(2018, 4, 3, 12, 25, 00).getTime() / 1000` (to get the seconds from the epoch) and pass it to my `DateTime` in the server side **I always get 3 hours before**, so in this example I'm getting `03-05-2018 09:25:00`

And this is how I'm parsing the `Date` in the server

```
DateTime sDt = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local))
  .AddSeconds(double.Parse(sessionDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DT"].ToString()));
```

Where the value of the `DataColumn` is the seconds from the JS `Date`

Why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: What timezone is your web server in? Your customer's main server in?

Comment: Mine is `UTC +2` but while I'm testing with custom seconds generated from my browser aren't they supposed to be the same?

Comment: My current time is `1;47PM`

Comment: Confirm that the timezone on the server is the same as your machine.  Otherwise the DateTimeKind.Local will change time to your local machine time and it will differ from the server values.  Ideally you should send time around in UTC.

Comment: Your local time is 3 hours away from UTC. That likely explains what you are seeing. One end is dealing with UTC and one is dealing with your timezone. https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript `Date.getTime` uses UTC, as documentation states:

> The getTime() method returns the numeric value corresponding to the
>   time for the specified date according to universal time.

So you should adjust your C# code like that:

```
DateTime sDt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) // <
    .AddSeconds(yourJsNumber).ToLocalTime();
```

If you don't need date in local timezone, you can omit `ToLocalTime` and work with it in UTC.